# emacs org-mode repeat task before deadline

Tags: org-mode

I have some confusion on emacs org data and times.

For example:

```
** TODO study English 
   DEADLINE: <2013-05-17 Fri> SCHEDULED: <2013-05-14 Thu ++1d>
```

After 2013-05-17, I don't want to show this task again. but right now in agenda view, it shows:

```
Friday     17 May 2013
  jtd:        Deadline:   TODO study English   

Saturday   18 May 2013
  jtd:        Scheduled:  TODO study English 

Sunday     19 May 2013
  jtd:        Scheduled:  TODO study English
```

How can I do this in org mode?